# Logstash - using mutate with split

Tags: filter, split, logstash

I'm trying to use the *mutate* filter with the *split* method, to extract a part of a field retrieved by the json filter. But I didn't find how to exploit the result of the split.
Here's my *logical* configuration (only the simple json part works well):

```
filter {
        if [type] == "phperrors" {
                json {
                        source => "message"
                        target => "phperror_log"
                        remove_field => "message"
                        add_tag => [ "php", "error" ]
                }
                mutate {
                        split => ["[phperror_log][server]", "."]
                        #if [phperror_log][server][1] {
                                add_field => [ "pop", "%{[phperror_log][server][1]}" ]
                        #}
                }
        }
}
```

As I said the json part works well and the phperror_log.server field exists (and the value is something like node01.ny or node01.par or node02).

But all I want is to create a new field if the split create an array of 2 fields and I suppose I'm not doing the right thing with my [phperror_log][server][1].

Have you any clues, advices or best practices to resolve this kind of use case?

Thanks in advance

edit: I edit with a conf that should work with the split... however the if is not ok

last edit with a nice conf according to the tips and advices from Alain:

```
filter {
        if [type] == "phperrors" {
                json {
                        source => "message"
                        target => "phperror_log"
                        remove_field => "message"
                        add_tag => [ "php", "error" ]
                }
                if [phperror_log][server] =~ /\./ {
                        mutate {
                                split => ["[phperror_log][server]", "."]
                                add_field => [ "pop", "%{[phperror_log][server][1]}" ]
                                add_field => [ "errorhost", "%{[phperror_log][server][0]}" ]
                        }
                } else {
                        mutate {
                                add_field => [ "pop", "not defined" ]
                                add_field => [ "errorhost", "%{[phperror_log][server]}" ]
                        }
                }
                mutate {
                        remove_field => [ "[phperror_log][server]" ]
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you split "node01.ny", your field will be ["node01", "ny" ].  Your example doesn't really show what you want to do with these split values, but the basic one would be to see if a value is contained in the array:

```
if "ny" IN [phperror.server] {
}
```

Note that add_field only runs if the filter is successful.  As such, you shouldn't need to check the array before adding the field.

That said, the split will only work if the field contained a ".".  You could conditional on that:

```
if phperror.server =~ /\./ {
  mutate {
     add_field => [ "hey", "i saw a period" ] 
  }
}
```

You example might show that you want to remove part of the value of the original field.  Try gsub:

```
gsub => [ "phperror.server", "\..*", "" ]
```

This would remove everything after the ".".

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, your explanation are really clear. I'll try it as soon as possible

Comment: nice, I will publish in the first post my last config file, it works well thank you Alain for your tip